# Using logistic regression in R to determine if cases and controls are different?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I'm sorry if this is a basic question - I'm really struggling to get my head around it.  I have a dataset of disease cases and healthy controls, and a score.  I want to see if the score is different between cases and controls.

I have a dataset, `my_data`, which looks like this:

```
my_data <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6", 
"ID7", "ID8", "ID9", "ID10", "ID11", "ID12", "ID13", "ID14", 
"ID15", "ID16", "ID17", "ID18", "ID19", "ID20", "ID21", "ID22", 
"ID23", "ID24", "ID25", "ID26", "ID27", "ID28", "ID29", "ID30", 
"ID31", "ID32"), case_status = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1), score = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 
3.15, 3.44, 3.44, 4.07, 3.73, 3.78, 5.25, 5.424, 5.345, 2.2, 
1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.52, 3.435, 3.84, 3.845, 1.935, 2.14, 1.513, 
3.17, 2.77, 3.57, 2.78), age = c(20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 20)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")

> head(my_data)
   ID case_status score age
1 ID1           0 2.620  20
2 ID2           0 2.875  20
3 ID3           1 2.320  20
4 ID4           1 3.215  15
5 ID5           0 3.440  15
6 ID6           1 3.460  15
```

I want to use a logistic regression model to see if `score` is different between `case_status` (`1` is diseased, `0` is not diseased).

So am I correct if I run:

```
model <- glm(
            case_status ~ score + age,
            data = my_data,
            family = binomial(link='logit')
        )
```

And then when I do
`summary(model)`

One of the outputs:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  10.9370     5.4987   1.989   0.0467 *
score        -2.5077     0.9866  -2.542   0.0110 *
age          -0.1809     0.1625  -1.113   0.2656
```

So score (p = 0.0110) is significantly different between cases and controls.  Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. In this case, you should use `score ~ case_status`. Your outcome is `score` and you want to see whether `case_status` predicts that outcome. And if you run the model (for example, with `family = gaussian(link = "identity")`), you will see that, controlling for age, those who have disease score lower than those who do not have disease ($\hat \beta=-0.881$).

Comment: I recommend checking a textbook on regression analysis, especially one using `R`. For instance, Fox & Weisberg's *An R Companion to Applied Regression* could be useful.